# Loop over Map in Shakespearean Templates

Tags: loops, haskell, dictionary, yesod

There is `@forall` in Shakespearean Templates to iterate over a List. Imagine that I have a `Data.Map.Map` of the form `m = Map.fromList [("key1","value1"),("key2","value2")]`. How can i produce the output

```
<li>key1 – value1</li>
<li>key2 – value2</li>
```

I already know the solution

```
$forall (k,v) <- Map.toList m
    <li>#{k} – #{v}
```

Is this the recommended solution?

Comment: That's the way I would do it. There are some newtype wrappers that you could use instead, but I like the explicit `Map.toList`.

Comment: Never heard of "newtype wrappers" before. What are they?

Comment: That's a pretty big topic for a comment here. In this case, newtypes are special wrapper types that allow different typeclass instances to exist. In this case, it would be a newtype so that the `Foldable` instance of a `Map` would provide the keys and values, not just the values. But as I said, I prefer the `Map.toList` approach. haskell-cafe or a separate question would be a good place to ask for more newtype details.